# Modify Microsoft form embedded webpart format on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, iframe, embedded, microsoft-forms

I have created a Microsoft form and embded the code in SharePoint page.

But I cannot modify the text on display of webpart.

As of now, the webpart on SharePoint page is as below

[image]

Now, how can I modify the the text like "Microsoft Form" to actual form name and change the background color?

And how to choose a format to

Comment: How you have embedded Microsoft form? did you use Embed webpart or any other way?

Comment: I embeded MS form directly and added "Embed" web part from SP site. I tried background-color in iframe code but failed to modify

Comment: Which link you have added in iframe? collect response link or any other link?

Comment: The embed link from Microsoft form. I didn't added any iframe

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to change the display text or theme for the embed code of Microsoft Forms.

See a related UserVoice post here: [Embed code with options.](https://microsoftforms.uservoice.com/forums/386451-welcome-to-microsoft-forms-suggestion-box/suggestions/31250707-embed-code-with-options)

In addition, there is another post with higher attention in the Forms UserVoice forum, where you can go and share this idea: [Sharing and collaborating experience in Forms.](https://microsoftforms.uservoice.com/forums/386451-welcome-to-microsoft-forms-suggestion-box/suggestions/41693890-sharing-and-collaborating-experience-in-forms)